# expression tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

I'm having some trouble understanding expression trees especially with putting this expression into a tree:

```
S/P^Q^R
```

Any help with how to do these is greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: Some more details would be nice. Is your expression an expression in propositional logic? What does "/" mean?

Comment: / is division. the expression is a regular arithmetic expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An expression tree is a tree that visualises the evaluation order of the expression.
In your case, since you have neither given any information on operator precedence or included parentheses in the expression, there is more than one possible expression tree.
If we assume that / is evaluated before ^, you would get an expression tree like

```
           "^"
          /   \
        "^"     R
       /   \
     "/"    Q
    /  \
   S    P
```

Working your way back up from the leaves to the root, you can recover the expression:
$$(S/P)$$
$$(S/P)^Q$$
$$((S/P)^Q)^R$$

If we assume that ^ is evaluated before /, there are two possibilities, either
$$S/((P^Q)^R) \quad \text{or}$$
$$S/(P^{(Q^R)}),$$
which would correspond to the expression trees

```
       "/"                          "/"
      /   \                        /   \
     S    "^"                     S    "^"
         /   \                        /   \
       "^"    R                      P    "^"
      /   \                              /   \
     P     Q                            Q     R
```

respectively. If you have no information with regards to operator precedence, then these three expression trees are all correct expression trees for your expression.

Comment: That is why I'm having trouble as that is all the information i have been given to answer the question. I would of assumed that the powers would have been first using the standard order of operations

Comment: @user3476732 Without any parentheses, the expression is ambiguous, and hence more than one expression tree can be given for the expression. I have extended my answer to mention this.

Comment: This is great thanks for your time